# tmp folder cakephp fake name folder

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Where did this folder store /tmp/phpX04qG5 . Or just a fake name?

```
array(
    'Image' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'name' => 'im.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpX04qG5',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 36970
        )
    )
)
```

I could see

```
array(
    'file' => array(
        'name' => '20140704_48566_im.jpg'
    )
)
```

In my current path which lab.domain.com/20140704_48566_im.jpg but /tmp/phpX04qG5 are missing.

Comment: hi. you dont need to access the temp folder. Just make sure you copy the file to your image folder. The system temp folder the OS cleaning by itself

Comment: **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_folder**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[upload_tmp_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)         ::From http://php.net

The temporary directory used for storing files when doing file upload. Must be writable by whatever user PHP is running as. If not specified PHP will use the system's default.

If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on, then the system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.

Other link where its described clearly : [click here](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/upload_tmp_dir.html)